# Set variables from variables?

Tags: python

I've got many, many strings, all formatted like this: "lot1", "lot2", "lot3"... What I'd like to do is use a function argument to determine which variable to use. Here's a pseudoexample:

```
def printlot(someInt):
    print lot%i % (someInt)
```

Basically, I'd like to use multiple strings to form the name of another string to act with. This seems simple enough, but I haven't learned how to do it in my two years of Pythoning.

Comment: The reason being that it's generally a bad thing to do.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead.  Create a dict called `lots` and access your values via `lots[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all visible variables as a dictionary using the `vars` builtin function:

```
vars()['lot%d' % someInt]
```

Different scopes can be accessed with `globals` or `locals`.

Note, however, that this is generally considered "unpythonic" behaviour. Instead of creating many similarly-named variables, a more Pythonic approach would be to make a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

What nneonneo said is correct, but you're really going to want to use a dict explicitly. That is, you want to do this:

```
lot_data = {'lot1': 10, 'lot2': 20, 'lot3': 30}
i = 2
print lot_data['lot%d' % i]
```

Instead of this:

```
lot1 = 10
lot2 = 20
lot3 = 30
i = 2
print vars()['lot%d' % i]
```